# display an image in php with a variable in place of image source

Tags: php, image

So I am trying to get products from my database to display along side an image. 
the images are stored in /webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics

```
echo '<img src="/webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics/PG211.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="stupid">';
```

This works fine.

however i want to be able to change the image source.
So i need something like this

```
$dir = '"/webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics/PG211.jpg"';
echo '<img src="$dir" width="100" height="100" alt="stupid">';
```

I would then manipulate $dir as needed but the above code does not work. 
am i missing something? the code runs without errors but doesnt display the image and instead displays the alt text.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: check quote issue in your string it's simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<img src="'.$dir.'" width="100" height="100" alt="stupid">';
```

you can use variable in double quotes, not in single.

Comment: Hi, This worked when I also removed the double quotes around /webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics/PG211.jpg as suggested by Ahmed thank you :)
I want to put this as the answer because I would never have thought about using '.$dir.' although i did try the removing of the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$dir = '"/webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics/PG211.jpg"';
echo '<img src="$dir" width="100" height="100" alt="stupid">';
```

with

```
$dir = '/webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics/PG211.jpg';
echo '<img src="$dir" width="100" height="100" alt="stupid">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove double quote from $dir variable:

```
$dir = '"/webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics/PG211.jpg"';
```

To

```
$dir = '/webERP/companies/bnh2012/part_pics/PG211.jpg';
```